# MYSQL SELECT with contradictory LIMITs

Tags: mysql, datetime, limit

There is a table with one date field

The question is:
Is there a way to select 10 records AFTER today AND 10 records BEFORE today :)

Of course, instead of making two queries

```
    SELECT xxxx FROM xxxx WHERE thedate >= 'date' ORDER BY thedate DESC LIMIT 10
```

and

```
 SELECT the same WHERE thedate < 'date' ORDER BY thedate ASC LIMIT 10
```

LIMIT is preferred. Just because of speed.

The data in thedate field is NOT predictable. There can be one or two records with the same date or no records for date.

Comment: i asked to find the way WITHOUT making 2 queries. as I understand, UNION makes separate SELECTs for each query and then creates temporary table with result. or maybe i am wrong? :)

Comment: So what? Why is a UNION query worrying you?

Comment: UNION is not worrying me. If there is NO way to make ONE query, then I'll make just two selects and that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT xxxx FROM xxxx WHERE thedate >= 'date' ORDER BY thedate DESC LIMIT 10
union all
SELECT xxxx FROM xxxx WHERE thedate < 'date' ORDER BY thedate ASC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT xxxx FROM xxxx WHERE thedate > CURDATE() ORDER BY thedate DESC LIMIT 10
union
SELECTxxxx FROM xxxx WHERE thedate < CURDATE() ORDER BY thedate ASC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substract both dates and make the difference absolute:

```
SELECT xxxx FROM xxxx ORDER BY ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(thedate) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('date'))
```

However, it would be much easier to just join the two queries using [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...
```

Comment: I asked for a way to NOT to make two queries ;)

Comment: I need a way to make ONE query with result of 20 records. UNION results in 3 queries (SELECT+SELECT+UNION)